# How can I check whether the protocol is implemented?

Tags: elixir

I wonder if there any way to ask Elixir whether *this object implements that protocol*, something like `obj |> implements(Enumerable)`?

Basically, I have to distinguish structs and maps. The solution I currently have is kinda ugly:

```
try
  obj |> Enum.each ...
rescue 
  e in Protocol.UndefinedError -> obj |> Maps.keys ...
end
```

The above works, but I would prefer to use pattern matching like:

```
cond do
  obj |> is_implemented(Enumerable) -> ...
  _ -> ...
end
```

Am I missing something? **Can one explicitly check whether the desired protocol is implemented by the object?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check whether `Protocol.impl_for(term)` returns nil or not:

```
iex(1)> Enumerable.impl_for []
Enumerable.List
iex(2)> Enumerable.impl_for {}
nil
iex(3)> Enumerable.impl_for MapSet.new
Enumerable.MapSet
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I wonder why it’s missing at http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enumerable.html

Comment: Probably because of https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/d02be44dd5deb763e5a0eb03f3c716506d781d08/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L430.